# System lags, stuttering

Tags: 18.04, performance

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, but I have some trouble where my PC is stuttering from time to time. The whole PC lags for about second and keeps on going. Wouldn't really be a problem, but it also happens when I play games, where it can be very annoying.

I would like to have some help, and type if you need any system information.

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #3 (rev 21)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #4 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.3G        2.3G        294M         88M        686M        655M
Swap:          975M        911M         64M
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Yes, of course, we need your system information in this type of question! Please [edit] your question to include your HW specification. You should also include the output of the `free -h` command, don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your RAM (3.3GB) seems to be quite low, your swap gets almost exhausted moreover. While your machine still fits the minimal requirements, it can be pretty limiting for more demanding applications. What applications (including games) are you running on this machine?

Comment: Only Half-Life: Counter-Strike (CS 1.6)